Visual Studio Code- how do I debug a loaded module?
In Powershell ISE, I was able to open a function code module in the ISE, set a breakpoint, in the command line window below, dot source the function code, then run the function from the command line with parameters and was able to debug the function.
I tried the same thing in VSC however it does not recognise the breakpoint when the function is run from the Terminal window. Is this possible?
My source for the module is this:
https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article?articleNumber=370419
For some strange reason when I try with the Broadcom supplied module, my ISE crashes to the desktop, even when run as an administrator so I'm forced to use VSC.
I tried to load the module in VSC and set a breakpoint and was expecting to run the module from the command line and for the code execution to stop at the breakpoint however it did not and thus I cannot debug the function code.
PS C:\Users\jmilano\Documents\PowerShell_Scripts\Bulk_License_Update-v1.0> Get-PowerCLIVersion
WARNING: The cmdlet "Get-PowerCLIVersion" is deprecated. Please use the 'Get-Module' cmdlet instead.
PowerCLI Version
VMware.PowerCLI 13.1.0 build 21624340
Component Versions
VMware Common PowerCLI Component 13.2 build 22643733
VMware Cis Core PowerCLI Component PowerCLI Component 13.2 build 22643734
VMware VimAutomation VICore Commands PowerCLI Component PowerCLI Component 13.1 build 21606170
PS C:\Users\jmilano\Documents\PowerShell_Scripts\Bulk_License_Update-v1.0> $PSVersionTable
Name                           Value

PSVersion                      7.4.5
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.4.5
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.20348
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PS C:\Temp> $PSVersionTable
Name                           Value

PSVersion                      5.1.20348.2760
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.20348.2760
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
